# Set up vim automatic coloring for FORTRAN

Tags: macos, vim, fortran

I cannot set the automatic coloring on vim for FORTRAN. I looked at the other thread on stackoverflow, and both of these lines in my .vimrc do not work:

```
syntax on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.f08 set filetype=fortran
```

The "syntax on" does actually works, but just underlines some part of the code. I want to have the conventional FORTRAN colors.

Comment: What do you mean by "conventional FORTRAN colors". Could you give a code example that is not correctly highlighted?

Comment: Note also that Fortran stopped being FORTRAN 22 years ago.

Comment: In Vim, what is the output of `:echo $TERM` ?

Comment: Vim 7.4.16 on archlinux ships with `fortran.vim` which states, that it supports Fortran 2008.

Comment: Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu is working with Fortran 2008 files as well...

Comment: by conventional colors, I just meant the pre-defined colors has for fortran @AlexanderVogt 

I ran the command `echo $TERM` on the terminal and got `xterm-256color` @romainl

Comment: Could you give a code example that is not correctly highlighted?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I dont have one, I just want colors on my vim, I guess my phrasing was wrong since the beginning. I've actually found that the colors just dont show up when I am using the pro theme. When I use the regular one, they do.Also, I never got the colors to work for     ls for with the "pro theme" (I read a bunch of topics on stack overflow but nothing worked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you were quite close to the solution. Adding the following lines to .vimrc works on my mac.

```
:syntax enable
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.f08 set filetype=fortran
```

PS.: I'm using the Terminal.app. If you use another Termial, the problem might be caused due to the value of TERM. Typing

```
echo $TERM
```

should e.g. give xterm-color. Alternatively it might be VT100, which doesn't support colors. But you can easily change this by setting:

```
TERM=xterm-color
```

in your Terminal. This you can of course also add to your .bash_profile or .bashrc or whatever file which is read on start-up.